# EF Core context.SaveChanges() getting executed before previous statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an internal tool at the company I work for that migrates data from an old SQLite database to a new SQL Server one. After I've done all my entity transforms, and added them to my destination context, I want to then commit those to the target database instance and update the user via the console that the commit operation is underway. However, whenever I run this, the string doesn't get printed to the console until after the context has finished flushing the changes.

The only thing I can think of is that then .NET Core runtime is dynamically reordering the operations for some reason, meaning the print statement doesn't get called until after the commit succeeds or fails. This is problematic in terms of UX for using the tool, as it's not clear whether anything is actually happening or not, as the tool will just appear to hang for a while.

Any ideas what's going on here or how I can force the statements to execute in the desired order?

```cs
private static void CommitChanges(InductosenseContext destinationContext)
{
    Console.Write("Committing changes to destination database...");
    destinationContext.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine(" DONE.");
}
```

Comment: perhaps another method is executing context.SaveChanges() before CommitChanges method

Comment: @JamalSalman, it's not; this is just a small tool and this is the only place where `SaveChanges()` is called.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if you use the debugger and put a breakpoint on `destinationContext.SaveChanges()`, nothing is printed in the console, right?

Comment: How are you determining that the changes are "flushed" before the console output completes?

Comment: @JamalSalman, correct.

Comment: @StevePy, because the app hangs for a while as the changes are committed, and the string is only printed to the console after it's finished the lengthy save change operation.

Comment: Is CommitChanges being called from a worker thread/task? While `Console.Write` can be called from background threads, it seems .Net Core has been tinkering with the performance of Console with regards to console logging and introducing a queue so it may be that in .Net Core 2.2 or 3 that the actual UI output does not block. (I find trying to dig up accurate behaviour changes for .Net core is a frustrating experience.)  I would try dispatching the console update back to the UI thread if you are running background. (Shouldn't have to, but with Core, any rule may be broken)

Comment: @StevePy, it's all just in the main method without using any tasks or threads.